# Cypher Query - Count function

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I tried to make a request but I'm having a bit of trouble with the cypher being new.
So my request in question: Calculate the number of apples which are in basket 1 and in basket 2 (knowing that apple, basket 1 and basket 2 are 3 different objects and that there is a relation of basket 1 -> apple and basket 2 -> apple)

I tried this :

```
MATCH (a:Apple)<-[:INCLUDE_ON]-(bO:BasketOne)-[:INCLUDE]->(bT:BasketTwo)

WITH a, bT, count(abT) as cnt

RETURN cnt;
```

But it doesnt works...
Thanks for your help!

Comment: How exactly does it not work? Do you have any errors? What do they say?

Comment: Basically instead of returning the number of apples in common that there is in basket 1 and basket 2, it just counts me the total number of apples in basket 2...

Comment: What does your data model look like ? can one basket be included in another ?

Comment: Please attach a picture of your data. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like we could leverage the common relationship like this:

```
MATCH (bO:BasketOne)-[:INCLUDE]->(a:Apple)<-[:INCLUDE]-(bT:BasketTwo)
RETURN count(a) as cnt;
```

The above query will return the count of apples that have an incoming 'INCLUDE' Relationship from bO and bT